# Dynamically generate drop-down lists and bind options with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

This fiddle demonstrates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/QMM5b/2/

One drop-down list will be create with the model, if "Add List" is clicked another one will be created OK, more clicks will produce unbound lists.

This is because the additional observables were created after the model was bound, so they are useless.

```
// this will create an observable which is not bound to the UI
if (!ko.isObservable(self.listData()[field]))
    self.listData()[field] = ko.observableArray([]);
```

I guess such scenario isn't that uncommon. What I could do is pre-prepare a big enough list of empty observables (for the self.listData and the self.data properties). My real big fat one page app requires an unknown number of controls (metaData loaded via JSON), so I was hoping there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the execution order is wrong in your code:

- First you need to create the new observable fields on the `self.listData()`
- and after that you need to add the field to the `self.metaData.push(field);` because that will trigger the `foreach` and by that time your observables will be already.

So your `addMetaData` should look like this:

```
self.addMetaData = function() {
    var field = "field" + self.fieldNum++;

    if (!ko.isObservable(self.listData()[field]))
        self.listData()[field] = ko.observableArray([]);

    if (!ko.isObservable(self.data()[field]))
        self.data()[field] = ko.observable("B");           

    self.listData()[field].push(new ListEntry("Value A", "A"));
    self.listData()[field].push(new ListEntry("Value B", "B"));

    self.metaData.push(field);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Ssq/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not take into consideration that the "outer" collection needed to be worked on. In the UI it would be nicer if I could process the metaData first (draw the drop-downs) and then asynchronously load the drop-down options (they may arrive via $.ajax a couple of 100ms later). Would that be a lot more complicated?

Comment: You can load the dropdown later, the point is the the `self.metaData.push(field);`  should come after the `self.listData()[field] = ko.observableArray([]);` http://jsfiddle.net/p33yX/